# how to include external code in Python similar as %include in SAS?

Tags: python, sas

I am trying to define a variable list `var_list` which includes hundreds of variables. So I want to do something similar as `SAS` to put this definition in an external code instead of the main code. Is there anyway to do that?

For example save the following code in another file called `def_var.py`

```
var_list= ['date_of_birth_year_month'
                             ,'zip5'
                             ,'zip4'
                             ,'state_province'
                             ,'city'
                             ,'zip5_ip'
                             ,'zip4_ip'
                             ,'create_user'
                             ,'create_dt'
                             ,'update_user'
                             ,'update_dt'
                             ,'resp_ST'
                             ,'resp_HomeTheater'
                             ,'resp_Headphone']
```

Comment: `from def_var import var_list`

Comment: You defined a list of strings. How do you expect to get them to be variables? What are their value?

Comment: have you heard about the [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) statement.

You can save your variables in `def_var.py` as:

```
var_list= ['date_of_birth_year_month'
,'zip5'
,'zip4'
,'state_province'
,'city'
,'zip5_ip'
,'zip4_ip'
,'create_user'
,'create_dt'
,'update_user'
,'update_dt'
,'resp_ST'
,'resp_HomeTheater'
,'resp_Headphone']
```

And import it in your `main.py`:

```
from def_var import var_list
# now you can work with your list
print(var_list[1])
```

Output:

```
zip5
```

Comment: where should I save the file "def_var.py"?

Comment: Can i import from some self defined project folder?

Comment: At my example it is in the same folder as the `main.py`. Other folders are possible with relative imports.

Comment: I have tested but got the following error:

from def_var import var_list
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-127-e02f65d32214>", line 1, in <module>
    from def_var import var_list

ImportError: No module named 'def_var'

Comment: def_var.py has to be in the same directory as your script. Sounds like Python didn't find the file. How are you using python? Per console or jupyter/ipython notebook?

Comment: I have already saved the code under the same folder and I am using Anaconda

Comment: Python version?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of Anaconda with python 3.6.0 to run the code. It does not work. But if I run the code using cmd window, it works.

Comment: I have figured out that once i change the directory of Anaconda, the code works

Answer (score 0):

For more sophisticated uses of sas, programmers will often have various macros/sas programs in different directories, each of which is specific to a certain type of workflow.  In these cases SAS %include will typically include the full path to whatever code is of interest.

```
%include "myfilepath/some_directory_of_macros/some_sas_macro.sas"
```

In python one specifies this in two steps

Step1:

Make sure that the directory with code base of interest is in the python search path.

Details:

```
import sys
sys.path
sys.path.append("myfilepath")
sys.path # checking to see if it was added to list
```

STEP2

Now you can import the code/function of interest.  The import will look sequentially through all the paths in sys.path, and stop once it finds a directory named some_directory_of_macros in one of the directories listed in sys.path.

```
import some_directory_of_macros

# SomePythonModule.py should be in some_directory_of_macros
from some_directory_of_macros.SomePythonModule
```

CAUTION, If some_directory_of_macros exists in more than one of the directories listed in sys.path, python will load the 1st one it finds

--> the sequence of paths in sys.path matters.

--> You can modify the order as you would normally do with any Python list if need be.